# Asymptotic behavior of finite sum?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, special-functions

$$\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \left(\frac{1}{\left(2k-1+2^{1/\alpha}\right)^\alpha} - \frac{1}{\left(2k+2^{1/\alpha}\right)^\alpha}\right),$$ where $0<\alpha<2$ and $\alpha\neq1$. Can someone help me in finding the asymptotic behavior of finite sum?

I already have the asymptotic behavior of this finite sum for $\alpha=1$.

Comment: What is the asymptotic behavior for $\alpha=1$?

Comment: for $\alpha=1$
$$\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \left(\frac{1}{\left(2k+1 \right)} - \frac{1}{\left(2k+2\right)}\right) \approx log(2) -\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4n}$$

Comment: Oh so you are looking for more than just the asymptotic value of the sum, but perhaps the next term of the asymptotic expansion?

Comment: yes. Do you have any idea for $\alpha>0$?

Comment: Actually I want to calculate asymptotic behavior of finite sum, by not ignoring any term by doing Taylor expansion.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know how we could make it for any value of $\alpha$.

However, we can notice that, if
$$S_n^{(\alpha)}=\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \left(\frac{1}{\left(2k-1+2^{1/\alpha}\right)^\alpha} - \frac{1}{\left(2k+2^{1/\alpha}\right)^\alpha}\right)$$ then $2^\alpha S_n^{(\alpha)}$ can write $$ -\zeta \left(\alpha ,1+2^{\frac{1}{\alpha }-1}\right)+\zeta \left(\alpha
   ,\frac{1}{2} \left(1+2^{\frac{1}{\alpha }}\right)\right)+\zeta \left(\alpha
   ,n+2^{\frac{1}{\alpha }-1}+1\right)-\zeta \left(\alpha ,\frac{1}{2}
   \left(1+2^{\frac{1}{\alpha }}\right)+n\right)$$ where appears the Hurwitz zeta function.

For $\alpha=2$, this would give
$$S_n^{(2)}=\frac{1}{4} \left(\zeta \left(2,\frac{1}{2} \left(1+\sqrt{2}\right)\right)-\zeta
   \left(2,1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\right)-\frac{1}{8
   n^2}+\frac{\frac{1}{16}+\frac{1}{4
   \sqrt{2}}}{n^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)$$ the constant coefficient being $\approx 0.116998$.

As shown in the table below, this seems to be quite good
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 n & \text{exact} & \text{approximation} \\
 5 & 0.1134940446 & 0.1139123171 \\
 6 & 0.1144254293 & 0.1146336438 \\
 7 & 0.1150296641 & 0.1151446828 \\
 8 & 0.1154436961 & 0.1155123159 \\
 9 & 0.1157396829 & 0.1157831196 \\
 10 & 0.1159585608 & 0.1159873803
\end{array}
\right)$$

It is interesting to notice that this is quite workable for integer values of $\alpha$ leading to something like
$$S_n^{(\alpha)}=C_\alpha-\frac 1 {2^{\alpha+1} n^\alpha}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^{\alpha+1}}\right)$$

May be, this could extend to non integer values of $\alpha$.

Comment: Dear, 
Many thanks for kind response. I have few questions are following
1. How did you compute $\zeta$ function for constants? i.e., $\zeta(2,\frac{1}{2}(1+\sqrt 2))$
2. when you are saying "the constant coefficient" $\approx 0.116998$, you mean that you computed $\frac{1}{4}(\zeta(2,\frac{1}{2}(1+\sqrt 2)) - \zeta(2,1+\frac{1}{\sqrt 2})) \approx 0.116998$ ? i'm right?

Comment: Dear, I have gone through the formal derivation of the series $S_n^{(2)}$,
 I'm totally agree with the constant term $\frac{1}{4} \left( \zeta(2, \frac{1}{2}(1+sqrt 2))  - \zeta(2, 1 + \frac{1}{sqrt 2} )\right) \approx 0.116998$. 
If I go a step further, can you tell me how did you compute $-\frac{1}{8n^2} + \frac{\frac{1}{16} + \frac{1}{4\sqrt 2}  }  {n^3} + O(\frac{1}{n^4})$?
I shall wait for your response.